# How to save an image in TIFF format?

Tags: imagesharp

I wonder if it's possible to save an image to TIFF format using the ImageSharp library, and if yes how to do it? I can't find any suitable methods on the Image class.

```
image.SaveAsJpeg() (shortcut for image.Save(new JpegEncoder()))
image.SaveAsPng() (shortcut for image.Save(new PngEncoder()))
image.SaveAsGif() (shortcut for image.Save(new GifEncoder()))
image.SaveAsBmp() (shortcut for image.Save(new BmpEncoder()))
image.SaveAsTga() (shortcut for image.Save(new TgaEncoder()))
```

Source: https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp/imageformats.html

In their GitHub repo there have been some work done, but I can't find any information in the project documentation.
https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/labels/formats%3Atiff

Answer (score 0):

Found a ongoing pull request for TIFF support in ImageSharp.

https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/pull/1553

Answer (score 0):

For those still finding this post, TIFF is now supported: https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp/imageformats.html